# Format time properly in Java

Tags: java, android, time

I've stumbled upon this method, which formats time until the alarm will go off. Sometimes, for example when I set the time to 13:46 and my mobile time is 13:44 I get the text that there is 1 minute remaining to my alarm, which is obviously false information. Here is the code that does the stuff:

```
private static String formatAlarmTime(Context c) {
    if (!App.getState().alarm().on()) {
        return "";
    }
    long t = App.getState().alarm().nextAlarm().getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis() - 1;
    t = t / 60 / 1000;
    int m = (int) (t % 60);
    int h = (int) (t / 60);

    String minSeq = (m == 0) ? "" :
            (m == 1) ? c.getString(R.string.minute) :
                    c.getString(R.string.minutes, Long.toString(m));

    String hourSeq = (h == 0) ? "" :
            (h == 1) ? c.getString(R.string.hour) :
                    c.getString(R.string.hours, Long.toString(h));

    int index = ((h > 0) ? 1 : 0) | ((m > 0) ? 2 : 0);

    String[] formats = c.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alarm_set);
    return String.format(formats[index], hourSeq, minSeq);
}
```

The Array mentioned is like this:

```
<string-array name="alarm_set">
    <item>This alarm is set for less than 1 minute from now</item>
    <item>This alarm is set for %1$s from now</item>
    <item>This alarm is set for %2$s from now</item>
    <item>This alarm is set for %1$s and %2$s from now</item>
</string-array>
```

By the way if anyone was interested, this code comes from [this site](https://github.com/trikita/talalarmo)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The code rounds down to an even number of minutes, so it will report 1 minute if the difference is between 1 and 2 minutes, which it is when the mobile time is 13:44: and the alarm is set for 13:46:00.

To round up instead of down:

```
int ms = (int) (t % (60 * 1000));
t = t / 60 / 1000;
if (ms > 0) {
    // Round up!
    t++;
}
int m = (int) (t % 60);
int h = (int) (t / 60);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: @Traabefi I'm not even sure it is broken. But I guess you would rather round the number of minutes up?

Answer (score 0):

As @KlasLindback states in his answer you problem is to do with your values being rounded during your calculation. This is because the `int` datatype you are using supports Integer values - whole numbers. In situations where you pass decimal values to an int data type it truncates (removes) the decimal part.

Instead during your calculation you should make sure that you are using a datatype that supports decimal values, such as `double`.

Once you've got your long t finding the remaining time you can do the following to extract the remaining hours mins and seconds:

```
double hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(t);
double mins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(t);
double secs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(t);
```

If you base your logic on these decimal values you should be able to achieve what you want in terms of selecting the correct array value.